# Negative arity exception in recursive macro

Tags: clojure, macros, arity

I'm trying a [coding challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110195/31224) that requires you to create code that compiles infinitely.

My first thought was a macro that expands to itself forever. I wrote up:

```
(defmacro a []
    (a))
(a)
```

This doesn't actually produce anything, but I expected it to loop forever. Instead however, I get a nonsensical arity exception:

```
Wrong number of args (-2) passed to: infinite-compile/a, compiling:...
```

If I try to give it an argument for kicks, it now complains that the macro doesn't expect any arguments.

If I have it actually produce calls to itself:

```
(defmacro a []
    `(a))
(a)
```

It fails with a StackOverflow, which I expected.

What's going on here? Why does it think I'm passing the macro "-2" arguments? The only possible thing I could think of is it has something to do with the 2 implicit `&` arguments that are passed to macros, but that's just a shot in the dark and doesn't actually explain what's going on.

To address the answer, this doesn't appear to be an issue with a multi-arity macro since it only has a 0-arity version. Also, explicitly passing the implicit arguments doesn't do anything:

```
(defmacro a []
    (a &form &env))
```

This yields:

```
Compiler Exception clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to: infinite-compile/a, compiling:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting `(a)` to be macroexpanded during the definition of `a`, when `a` is not yet known to be a macro (and thus expected to be a function), whereas when you quote the form, you are effectively building a macro which expands into a call to itself.

When the compiler macroexpands a macro, it adds the implicit arguments before calling the function associated with the macro: [Compiler.java#L6795](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/b80e1fe4b14654d943e2f8b060b0bc56e18b4757/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6795). Here, you are directly calling `a`, which is in the scope of the implicit `defn` ([core.clj#L452](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/e547d35bb796051bb2cbf07bbca6ee67c5bc022f/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L452)), without passing the necessary arguments.

I would expect the following to work as you wish (loop):

```
user=> (defmacro a[]&form)
#'user/a
user=> (a)
```

But unfortunately, here is the error message I get:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'user/a, compiling:(/tmp/form-init5239882861501900074.clj:1:1)
```

... even though:

```
user=> (defmacro a[](print &form))
#'user/a
user=> (a)
(a)nil
```

NB. The Common Lisp equivalent is:

```
(defmacro w(&whole w)w) ;; 23 bytes
```

### Existing names

Note also that once you define `a`, your cannot change the definition as follows:

```
(defmacro a[](a 0 1))
```

... because it complains that `a` accepts zero arguments. If, however, you define *another* macro with a name which has not yet been defined, it works:

```
user=> (defmacro b[](b 0 1))
#'user/b
user=> (b)

StackOverflowError   user/b (form-init5239882861501900074.clj:1)
```

Comment: Still a little confused since I obviously don't understand very well how macros are implemented, but this generally makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Macros just take code and emit code (see also https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/e547d35bb796051bb2cbf07bbca6ee67c5bc022f/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3978). But you found some corner cases where the behavior is not necessarily intuitive nor sensible.

Comment: I understand that part. You mentioned though an "implicit defn". Does `defmacro` emit a `defn`? Maybe I'll look over the source of `defmacro` again.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The `(list 'do 'defn ...)` part builds code which defines a function and declare that the name is bound to a macro. That code might be eval'd by the compiler, for example (did not check).

Answer (score -1):

For more description of the problem see the ticket at http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1279.

Comment: This isn't an answer by Stack Overflow standards. It would be helpful instead as a comment on the question or on an existing answer, or if you additionally summarized here the important content found at that link.